# C# and saving date field to MS Access database

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access-2007

I am new to Access and saving data to it. I have a date time field which I used in Visual Studio to make the form and chose date time picker. I am not sure where I am going wrong but I know it is the calendar picker causing the issue. I get error syntax error in insert to statement.

Here is the code I have

```
string When = qaWhendateTimePicker.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

then my save query

```
 SQLString = "INSERT INTO QAAnswers (QuestionID,CallMonitorNumber,When) VALUES('"+QuestionID + "','" + CallMonitorNumber + "','" + When + "');";
```

This is of course the shorten version. But for the love of me if I take out the when it saves to the database fine

The Access database I have WHEN SET AS DATE / TIME.

Should I have it set to text? I would think no because then I can not pull queries based on date.

Thanks in advance as I been at this for many hours.

UPDATE

Per comment below i have changed the syntax. Here is what i have. If i put the .value or .date it does not work. I am sure it is something I am doing wrong. I get the error failed to convert parameter value from datetimepicker  to datetime.  Thanks as I am learning a lot doing this in access.

```
ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into QAAnswers ([CallMonitorNumber],[When],[ProperGreeting],[AssureHelp],[AccountVerification],[ConfirmCaller],[ProperPoliciesSolutions],[ProperPoliciesAdmin],[AppropriateTools],[TroubleshootingSteps],[ConfirmResolved],[CustomerEducation],[CSATSurvey],[ThanksCallerBrand],[ProfessionalToneAttitude],[CustomerInvolved],[CallPace],[Empathy],[PhoneEtiquette],[DiffuseEscalated],[UnacceptableCallPractice],[Notes],[ScorePotential],[ScoreActual],[FinalScore]) values (@CallMonitorNumber,@When,@ProperGreeting,@AssureHelp,@AccountVerification,@ConfirmCaller,@ProperPoliciesSolutions,@ProperPoliciesAdmin,@AppropriateTools,@TroubleshootingSteps,@ConfirmResolved,@CustomerEducation,@CSATSurvey,@ThanksCallerBrand,@ProfessionalToneAttitude,@CustomerInvolved,@CallPace,@Empathy,@PhoneEtiquette,@DiffuseEscalated,@UnacceptableCallPractice,@Notes,@ScorePotential,@ScoreActual,@FinalScore)", con);

ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agentIDNumbertextBox.Text.ToString();
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CallMonitorNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = qaCallMonitorNumbertextBox.Text.ToString();
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@When", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = qaWhendateTimePicker;
```

UPDATED ANSWER

I finally figured it out. Not sure if this is the best way but i just ignored the datetimepicker. I wish i could use the datepicker.  Instead i just input the date it was added in by using this statement  (shorten version ) Notice the [when] and the Date() .

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into QAAnswers ([CallMonitorNumber],[When]) values (@CallMonitorNumber,Date())", con);
```

I hope this helps someone else. I really do not like using access for a DB but that is what i have to work with .

I gave points to marc as i never heard of parametrized query

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: Look at the last characters of your line >> `"');";` and remove `";`

Comment: Why did you call your column `When`?

Comment: I could call it whatever but i was testing. Also If i take "; it shows an error

Comment: just change the `,'" + When + "')` to `,#" + When + "#)` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **parametrized query** to do the insert, to avoid SQL injection attacks!

Something like this:

```
SQLString = "INSERT INTO QAAnswers (QuestionID, CallMonitorNumber, When) VALUES(?, ?, ?);";
```

and then when you prepare your insert statement, you need to add three parameters (in Access typically defined as `p1`, `p2`, `p3`) and assign values to those.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(YourConnectionStringHere))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQLString, conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = QuestionID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = CallMonitorNumber;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = When;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

This will also take care of avoiding issues with dates in string format, and issues with single quotes and all those messy things.

Comment: if i change to how you have it will i have to add a datasource ? or can i still call it by using the sql string ?

Comment: @matthewmoore: no need for a data source - just use the code I posted - that "runs" the `INSERT` and should insert that data into your MS Access database

Comment: well i have one issue. I did the code and it gave an error failed to convert parameter value from datetimepicker to date time. Thank you for your help so far. I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: @matthewmoore: well, you need to assign the **value** of the date time picker (`qaWhendateTimePicker.Date` or `qaWhendateTimePicker.Value`) to your parameter - not the whole DateTimePicker as an object .....

Comment: I updated my code per what you wanted. I had that first time around but could not get date working so thought i would try again way . Thanks again. Sorry I am just slow on getting this.

Comment: @matthewmoore: can you assign the date time picker's value to a regular `DateTime` variable? `DateTime myDateTime = qaWhendateTimePicker.Value;` ?? Does that work?

Comment: I am sorry but i do not understand where to make the change.

Comment: I did change to this and still same issue ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@When",OleDbType.DBDate ).Value = DateTime.Now ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also:-
write your insert query in a stored procedure(or you can use query directly) then call it in your method

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
con.ConnectionString = strcon;
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Your_StoredProcedureName]", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", value1);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", value2);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", value3);

int result = da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
return result ;
```

Comment: The OP is using **MS Access** (not SQL Server) - so using `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` **won't work**!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Not sure if this is the best way but i just ignored the datetimepicker. I wish i could use the datepicker. Instead i just input the date it was added in by using this statement (shorten version ) Notice the [when] and the Date() .

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into QAAnswers ([CallMonitorNumber],[When]) values (@CallMonitorNumber,Date())", con);
```